# All possible combination with condition

Tags: python, combinations

I would like to generate all possible combination with some condition. Given that I have a data frame contain condition I needed.

```
Variable     Cluster_no sub_group
GDP_M3       1          GDP
HPI_M3_lg2   1          HPI
FDI_C_lg5    1          FDI
FDI_M6       2          FDI
Export_M9    2          Export
GDP_M9       2          GDP
GDP_M12_lg7  3          GDP
Export_M12   3          Export
```

I have found `itertools.combinations` that giving me all possible combination of 3 for example. However, I would like to consider more criteria with `cluster_no` and `sub_group`.

Having said that if I start with `GDP_M3` from `cluster 1`, it will not be matched with either `HPI_M3_lg2` or `FDI_C_lg5` because it comes from the same cluster. Given cluster condition, it will look for other clusters, which are `cluster 2` or `cluster 3`.

In `cluster 2`, there are 2 possible variables, which are `FDI_M6` or `Export_M9` because I would like to consider `sub_group` condition as well. If selecting `FDI_M6`, it will move to the next cluster because again it is allowed only 1 variable from each cluster.

For now, my list is `[GDP_M3, FDI_M6]`. The next variable for the combination is `Export_M12` because it is from `cluster 3` and `sub_group Export`.

I would like to set up to 3 possible combination (1 to 3). Any suggestion on this.

Thank you.

Edit to add my code.

```
N=3
combination=[]

for i in range(1, N+1):
    for j in itertools.combinations(a, i):
        combination.append(list(j))
```

Comment: it would be much clear if you could provide us with the code that you tried

Comment: why not perform combinations on the Variables themselves , taking the number of combinations in each cluster as unique values of a cluster belonging to that variable? iterate over a for loop with all the conditions you need

Comment: @NiteyaShah Because I need a combination with variable form other cluster. If I were do the combination in each cluster, the GDP_M3 will not be matched with Export_M12.

Comment: I meant a nested for loop ie for i in var1: for j in var2 if(i==j): pass

Comment: @Netwave revised

Comment: @NiteyaShah Could you provide the example?

Comment: Before I write the code can you please expand a bit on your sub group conditions

Comment: @NiteyaShah sub_group is the RAW formation for variable i.e. GDP after transformation will be GDP_M3, GDP_M6 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think with the builtin combination method can handle this kind of conditions. You have to write your own backtrack combination algorithm. I have already tried to implement one:

```
all_possible_combinations = []
def get_combinations(N, data, cur_index=0, generated_el=[], cluster_tracker=set(), sub_group_tracker=set()):
    if N == 0:
        if generated_el:
            all_possible_combinations.append(tuple(generated_el))
        return

    if cur_index >= len(data):
        return

    get_combinations(N, data, cur_index+1, generated_el, cluster_tracker, sub_group_tracker)

    if data[cur_index][1] in cluster_tracker:
        # I have already taken this cluster
        return

    if data[cur_index][2] in sub_group_tracker:
        # I have already taken this sub group
        return

    generated_el.append(data[cur_index][0])
    cluster_tracker.add(data[cur_index][1])
    sub_group_tracker.add(data[cur_index][2])
    get_combinations(N-1, data, cur_index+1, generated_el, cluster_tracker, sub_group_tracker)  
    generated_el.pop()
    cluster_tracker.remove(data[cur_index][1])
    sub_group_tracker.remove(data[cur_index][2])

    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [
        ("GDP_M3", "1", "GDP"),
        ("HPI_M3_lg2", "1", "HPI" ),
        ("FDI_C_lg5", "1", "FDI"),
        ("FDI_M6", "2", "FDI"),
        ("Export_M9", "2", "Export"),
        ("GDP_M9", "2", "GDP"),
        ("GDP_M12_lg7", "3", "GDP"),
        ("Export_M12", "3", "Export")
    ]

    get_combinations(3, data)
    print(all_possible_combinations)
```

You can see the output here: https://ideone.com/HwruJ7

Answer (score 1):

My method is similar to @Ahmad Faiyaz

```
from collections import defaultdict
x= [[1,1,'gdp'],[2,1,'hpi'],[3,1,'fdi'],[4,2,'fdi'],[5,2,'export'],[6,2,'gdp'],[7,3,'gdp'],[8,3,'export']]
c=defaultdict(list)
for i in x:
    c[i[1]]+=[i]

def rec_cal(i,clus,lis):
    if i in c.keys():
        for j in c[i]:
            if j[2] not in clus:
                clus.append(j[2])
                lis.append(j[0])
                rec_cal(i+1,clus,lis)
                clus.pop()
                lis.pop()
            else:
                continue
    else:
        print(lis)

rec_cal(1,[],[])
```

and you get the output as

```
[1, 4, 8]
[2, 4, 7]
[2, 4, 8]
[2, 5, 7]
[2, 6, 8]
[3, 5, 7]
[3, 6, 8]
```

This method first builds a cluster collection with the help of a dictionary and then recursively goes through the clusters taking into consideration the sub groups to create the final output. for now i am simply print it but you can easily capture it